# Create a second calendar for users in Exchange 2007

Tags: calendar, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

I need to programmatically create a second calendar for all our users in Exchange 2007. Can someone suggest the best way to get this done?

Comment: In an outlook macro, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this using EWS.  You want to create a folder of type, calendar.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563574(v=EXCHG.140).aspx) to get started.